# System.Net.WebSockets Ping/Pong

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

Does ClientWebSocket in System.Net.WebSockets automatically support ping/pong, meaning will my ClientWebSocket automatically respond with a pong if a ping is received from the server, or is this something I need to implement myself?

Also where does the ClientWebSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval come in? How does that differ from ping/pong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is handled implicitly by the client. See the source code below.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dc9c9d5f9e23ff6aa0b99af8f6c410a0558fadaf/src/libraries/System.Net.WebSockets/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L777-L781